# Nokogiri ruby: Iterate over table rows with no class name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to iterate over each row of a table.
This is the relevant source code showing 6 table rows in total.
3 of them have no class name and 3 others do, the ... represent some attributes.

```
<tbody>

    <tr> … </tr>
    <tr class="even"> … </tr>
    <tr> … </tr>
    <tr class="even"> … </tr>
    <tr> … </tr>
    <tr class="even"> … </tr>

</tbody>
```

Assuming that doc is a Nokogiri::HTML::Document the following code generates only 3 tr elements instead of 6. It only returns the tr elements having the class="even".

```
doc.css('#main_result table tbody tr').each do |tr|
  p tr
end
```

How can I now get an array of all tr elements, making it able to iterate over them?

This actual HTML can be found on the following link:
http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/1949/TT/500cc/RAC

I don't really know how to paste the source code nicely... sorry

Comment: can you give the actual HTML of the entire table?

Comment: All works well here, are you sure there isn't another similar structure in the document and you're scraping from there? If you try tr.text, you should get the all the elements.

Comment: I tried with the tr.text but it only gives the classes with 'even'. The other 3 elements without a class name don't show up.
Although, using
    doc.css('#main_result table tbody').each do |tr|
      p tr
    end
gives all td's of all 6 tr's. But I want to iterate over each tr and not over each td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML in that page is malformed, and is missing some `<tr>` tags, it actually looks something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note how only the `tr` tags with `class="even"` are present, the others are missing. Nokogiri therefore only sees three rows when parsing the page.

One possible solution to this could be to use [Nokogumbo](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/), which adds Google’s Gumbo HTML5 parser to Nokogiri, and better handles and corrects malformed HTML like this:

```
require 'nokogumbo' # install the gem first

doc = Nokogiri.HTML5(the_page)

puts doc.css('#main_result table tbody tr').size
# should now be 6 rather than 3
```